# awk pattern matching

Tags: regex, awk

In a line like this

> 21zCases-Peripherals  Combo   LOGITECH    176-83-LODMK250 LOGITECH
>   WIRELESS DESKTOP MK250
>   920-002653    920-002653  ΔΙΑΘΕΣΙΜΟ   16,90
>     0,24    22,82

i'm trying to extract `/176-83-LODMK250/`  with `/^[0-9]\{2,3\}-[0-9]\{2,3\}-*/)print $i`

but is not working.

Some suggestions??

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The ^ at the begining will try to find it in the begining of the string which is not the case. Also the * at the end of your expression will match upto the end of string.

Comment: Hello! ^ at the begining   is  the case because i need string that start with digit not [a-z]

Comment: The target string does **not** start with your desired string. So having a ^ in regex will never match. Try removing the ^ symbol from the expression and you will see a match.

Comment: pattern is start with 2or3 digit after"-" and after again 2or3 digit after another"-" and after everything

Comment: Yes and because your **desired** pattern appears in **middle** of the string, you cannot have a ^ in your pattern. Having a ^ inside pattern will **only** match if the original string **starts** with your pattern. I am at loss of words now getting this across.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by d-live, you need to remove the ^.  The ^ matches the "beginning of the whole string" (i.e. before "21zCases" in your example), not the "beginning of the matched string".

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
/[0-9]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3}-[^[:space:]]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Below regular expression works,

```
  echo "21zCases-Peripherals Combo LOGITECH 176-83-LODMK250 LOGITECH WIRELESS DESKTOP MK250 920-002653 920-002653 ΔΙΑΘΕΣΙΜΟ 16,90 0,24 22,82" | grep -i "[0-9]\{2,3\}-[0-9]\{2,3\}-.*"
```